# Extracting table from a webpage in automation anywhere

Tags: web-scraping, rpa, automationanywhere

Is there a way to extract a table from a web page in Automation Anywhere after taking certain steps using web recorder. The table does not appear directly, it appears after clicking few controls after launching the URL.
The table that I want to extract is coming after loggin in to the website and filtering using a control for search criteria.

I used web recorder to login and putting the desired search criteria in a text field and I want to extract the table now. When I use web recorder, it launches the URL again and takes me back to the login page which I dont want. I want the bot to stay on the page. Pls help.

Also, what is the significance of session name of an extracted table?

Comment: Welcome to stackoverflow. Please take the [tour] of the site to understand how stackoverflow works and how to ask good  questions. Then come back and [edit] your question. Include the code of what you've tried as a [mcve], plus any error messages. Ask specific questions. Most people are happy to help, but don't want to do your work for you. Questions like "how do I do x?" that don't show any research effort on your end are likely to get ignored.

Answer (score 1):

If you clicked on Advanced View, you will find at Step 5 : to run this command using an existing IE window. Try to write the URL of the page with the table and not the one of the login page.

The extracted table is to be used using variable $Table Column(Index)$ with index being the column number or column name

Answer (score 0):

you can export directly using object cloning and in the selection criteria export to csv file. But we need to click on html inner text also in search criteria

Answer (score 0):

An old question, but my experience has been the Extract Data/Table commands are rather poor. Not only do they only work in IE, you cannot call them as commands, they have to be called via a web recording.

Instead, I've found it much more useful to object clone the initial element, grab the DOMXPath, and variablize that. Then throw it into a loop while command and set the condition on finding at least one element (of the elements for the table you are trying to build). You can grab all sorts of useful info in the object clone command and then right that to a variable/table.

For example

```
//div[@id='updatable-standings']/div[1]/div[1]/div[2]/div[1]/table[1]/tbody[1]/tr[3]/td[2]/div[1]/span[2]
//div[@id='updatable-standings']/div[1]/div[1]/div[2]/div[1]/table[1]/tbody[1]/tr[4]/td[2]/div[1]/span[2]
```

I can create a incremental variable for {tr[3]} and call it $vTeamLoop$ and change my DOMXPath value in the Object Clone to be

```
//div[@id='updatable-standings']/div[1]/div[1]/div[2]/div[1]/table[1]/tbody[1]/tr[$vTeamLoop$]/td[2]/div[1]/span[2]
```

Ultimately, it is more steps than the Data/Table Extract command, but it is far less limited in scope.

Hope that helps.

```
enter code here
```

Comment: Just happened to come across my old question I asked in my learning phase. Thanks and my thoughts totally reciprocate yours. I found object cloning much more fail proof than web recorder.